# How to install high availability of OpenAM version 14

Tags: openam

Can someone please share high-availability installation steps of OpenAM version 14.5.2.

Trying to get solution

Answer (score 0):

You can check Open Identity Platform Community [wiki](https://github.com/OpenIdentityPlatform/OpenAM/wiki), there are several articles about different OpenAM installation and configuration methods.